# regex is it possible to match a line that does not containg the same word repeated anywhere on the line?

Tags: regex, string

how to select a line that contains one word but not repeated.
let say i am looking for the string word1

text word1 text   #matched

text word1 text word1   #not match , cause word1 is repeating.

word1 word1 word1       # not match , is repeating

word1 #matched

text text text text word1 # matched

can anyone giveme a hand how to develop a regex for matching those line??

Comment: If you know what word you're looking for, why not (a) split your string into an array of lines, (b) run match all in whatever language you're using with your sought word, and (c) isolate only the lines where the word was found once?

Comment: It would help us a lot if you gave us real example data and real expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\b\w+\b)(?!.*\1)
```

It uses a negative look ahead to a back reference to a captured word

Comment: well indeed this is a better answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
 ^(?!.*(\bword1\b).*\b\1\b).*\bword1\b.*$
```

here `word1` can be replaced with `\w+` if you want to match any word..

use it with `multiline` option

Comment: very good, i have to study this kind of regex, thanks for answering

Comment: @alex if that has solved your problem..you can accept the ans or atleast upvote